# How to show that $(n-k)!n^{\underline{k}}=\Gamma(n+1)$

Tags: binomial-coefficients, factorial

I want to show that, $\forall n,k\in\mathbb{N}$:
$${{n}\choose{k}}=\dfrac{n^{\underline{k}}}{k!}$$
And I have the following with $\Gamma(n)=(n-1)!$:
\begin{align*}
{{n}\choose{k}}-\dfrac{n^{\underline{k}}}{k!}&=\dfrac{n!}{k!(n-k)!}-\dfrac{n^{\underline{k}}}{k!}\\
    &=\dfrac{n!}{k!(n-k)!}-\dfrac{(n-k)!n^{\underline{k}}}{k!(n-k)!}\\
    &=\dfrac{\Gamma(n+1)}{k!(n-k)!}-\dfrac{\Gamma(n+1)}{k!(n-k)!}, \text{ thanks to WolframAlpha}\\
    &=0
\end{align*}

But how did WolframAlpha to show that $(n-k)!n^{\underline{k}}=\Gamma(n+1)$??

Comment: Quick question.  Can you prove that$$\frac{n!}{(n-k)!}=n^{\underline k}$$If so, then you can stop your proof at the first line.

Comment: @SimplyBeautifulArt n!/(n-k)!=(1.2.3.....n)/(1.2.3...(n-(k-1))(n-k))=(1.2.3...(n-(k-1))(n-k)....n)/((1.2.3...(n-(k-1))(n-k))=n(n-1)(n-2)(n-3)....(n-(k-1))

Comment: @SimplyBeautifulArt I understand now, thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note

$$n^{\underline{k}}=n \times (n-1) \times (n-2) \times \dots (n-k+1) \tag{1}$$
Also $$k!=k \times (k-1) \times (k-2) \times \dots \times 1 \tag{2}$$
So since $$n!=\{n \times (n-1) \times (n-2) \times \dots (n-k+1)\} \times \{k \times (k-1) \times \dots\times 1\}$$
This is just $(1) \times (2)$.

Comment: :P Stealing my hints

Comment: @SimplyBeautifulArt Sorry, saw your comment while typing.

Comment: @PMC1234 Your welcome.